# How to make sure a query executed successfully

Tags: perl, dbi

I need to execute a select statement query and capture the returned result and store it in a variable.

The execute isn't returning any data. I have checked my connection is correct since it's not returning any error.

> $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $username, $password)
>              or die $DBI::errstr;

The following is my query

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('select abc from pqr');
$sth->execute();
```

Now I am checking whether it has some data

```
if($sth->rows) {
    print "We have data!\n";
} else {
    print"No Data";
}
```

It always printing `No Data`.

For fetching the data I am using following

```
while(my @data = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    print "$data[1]\n";
}
$dbh->disconnect;
```

I am not getting any data.
Can anyone please suggest me what thing can be wrong here?
Same Query is giving me desired result with Java.

Comment: I would check the return value of the `execute`. `$sth->execute() or die "check dbi error msg"`

Comment: @chrsblck I have added the die statement but I am not getting the message "check dbi error msg" it meens Query Executed successfully.Then Why I am not getting the desired result. What I am getting empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the DBI [docs](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/dbi/appa_07.htm)

> $rv = $sth->rows;
>
> Returns the number of rows affected by the last row-affecting command,
>   or -1 if the number of rows is not known or not available.
>
> Generally, you can only rely on a row count after a non-SELECT execute
>   (for some specific operations like UPDATE and DELETE), or after
>   fetching all the rows of a SELECT statement.

WRT your:

```
while(my @data = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    print "$data[1]\n";
}
```

Asking for the second ([1]) element of the row doesn't make sense for your query.

Comment: Thank You So much. Now I am getting the result. It was my silly mistake . I was fighting from last 2 hours. I used $data[0] and got the result . Thank You so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not dealing with large result sets then fetching everything is a little faster

```
my $rows = $db->selectall_arrayref(qq|Select abc from def|) or die "Can't select " . $db->errstr();
if (@$rows) {
    print "I have rows";
    foreach my $row (@$rows) {
        # do something with $row->[0]
    }
} else {
    print "I did not get any rows/data";
}
```

Just another way of doing it